# Find the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x+y+z=11$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

How do I find the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x+y+z=11$ provided that $x\leq 3, y\leq 4, z\leq 6$ using the sum rule (counting)?

I know the answer is 6, but I'm having difficulty understanding why.

Comment: If this problem is from a book, and the hint is use sum rule, what is the statement from the book of the sum rule? [the term "sum rule" has many possible meanings]

Comment: In two dimensions the sum rule says if $A$ and $B$ are non-disjoint sets, then the total number of ways both sets may be ordered differently is $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$

Comment: There's a formula that generalizes it but it is so messy I'm not able to get it right or make sense of it

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem without the restrictions that $x \leq 3, y \leq 4, z \leq 6$?  If so, please show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to expand $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$$ and get the coefficient of $x^{11}.$